# Apache user doesn't have write permissions for database on shared server

Tags: php, database, apache, sqlite, permissions

I'm on a shared server and this isn't where apache is installed. Apache is installed on server A while i'm on server B (the shared server, where i have limited access). I don't know how Apache is configured since I don't have access to server A.

Server A has remote access to certain directories on server B, e.g. `public_html/` and its subdirectories are found and can be accessed and run by Apache.

I have a sqlite3 database on server B that i can read from just fine as the `apache` user but i can not write to it as the `apache` user, because the user `apache` doesn't have write permissions.

I know the user running my php is `apache` because i ran

```
echo `whoami`;
```

in my php code.

I know server B is Linux, specifically `RHEL Workstaion 6.5`.

I believe server A is Linux also, since `whoami` worked.

I know there is no user `apache` on server B.

Trying to insert into the database yields

> attempt to write a readonly database.

I retrieve the error message using `$dbHandle->lastErrorMsg();`

**Things i have tried:**

- Went through the php, sqlite3, apache forums as well as went through all the questions on stackoverflow that sounded like they had something related to my problem.
- I have chmod the database and its containing directory to have more permissions

  - I first tried chmod 764 for both and then
  - tried 766 for both but neither of them were able to get the user "apache" to write to my database.
- Explicitly telling sqlite3 to open my database in read write mode with `SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE`.

  - for each of the three permissions 744, 764 and 766.
- I've looked for other users that are using a database on server B but all the ones i found were using it only for reads.
- I tried using mysql but its not installed on server B and server A can't use the socket for a local install because its not on the same machine.

**Things i would've tried but aren't able to**

1. use chown to make `apache` the owner of the database - I'm not able to because `apache` is a user on server A
2. same as 1 but for user `www-data` that user is on server A

How can I get write access to my sqlite3 database that is accessed by the user `apache` that is a user of server A while my files including my database is on server B?

Comment: How are you connecting to the other server to read the file? NFS? SMB? FTP?

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with your database connections (not directly anyways). Are you sure your database ports are open?

Comment: I am able to connect to the database, and read from it, but the user "apache" doesn't have write permissions, so inserts updates and deletes dont work. while selects do work.

Comment: the connection to the other server is a mystery to me, but i think it goes through "server B"s files looking for directories named public_html and linking to them to serve them to any one who requests them.

Comment: @user3742756 — So server B downloads the database from server A over HTTP each time it wants to access it?

Comment: @Quentin i think that server A makes a link to the remote directory on server B so every time server A receives a request it tries to make the changes on the link but doesnt have write permission as the user "apache"

Comment: What is "a link to the remote directory on server B"? How is it achieved? You have to understand what your software is trying to do before you can work out how to fix it or change it.

Comment: Thats just it i don't have access to server A so how it gets my files is a mystery to me. All i really know is that it knows about the files on server B (a shared server with 300 or so users)that are in a directory named public_html

Comment: Then you should be able to see what Server B is doing to get the file, even if you can't see what Server A is doing to respond with the file.

Comment: server B just has directories, it isnt doing anything special. Server A finds, acceses somehow and serves it using an AMP stack

Comment: So you can see the sqlite file somewhere on Server B's filesystem? But you know it is sitting on a physical disk connected to Server A? So look at the file system configuration (e.g. with `mount`) to see how it is connected.

Comment: yes the sqlite file is on server B's filesystem. from mount it appears as if its connected to via nfs

Comment: So your question essentially boils down to "How can I configure NFS to allow the user 'apache' on the client to read and write to a file owned by 'www-data' on the server?". I suspect http://serverfault.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try asking there.